# Cannot access devise current_admin_user in AcitveAdmin form definition

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, activeadmin

I need to display some form fields in ActiveAdmin form only to specific users.
But when I try to check user status with this code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store do
  # ...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Basic" do
      if current_admin_user.super_admin?
        f.input :admin_user
      end
     # ...
     end
  end
end
```

I get

```
undefined local variable or method `current_admin_user' for #<ActiveAdmin::DSL:0xdb8e798>
```

CanCan methods also don't work in the ActiveAdmin form definition.

Generally my question is: how can I manage admin interface display, based on current user type?
Particularly, how can I get current devise user object from within ActiveAdmin definitions?

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of scope. You could try accessing the helper method using the f.template object like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store do
  # ...
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Basic" do
      if f.template.current_admin_user.super_admin?
        f.input :admin_user
      end
     # ...
     end
  end
end
```

Good luck.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I was experiencing the same problem and this answer is on the right track. It was probably correct in 2012, but in my case I was able to get the admin user with `f.template.controller.current_admin_user` instead of `f.template.current_admin_user`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this issue. In /app/admin/stores.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Store do
  # ...
  form :partial => 'form'
  # ...
end
```

and then in /app/views/admin/stores/_form.html.haml:

```
= semantic_form_for [:admin, @store] do |f|
  = f.inputs "Basic" do
    - if current_admin_user.super_admin?
      =f.input :admin_user
```

It's not convenient at all, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little old but I just found a nice little fix for this. I'm not using devise, I'm using the Twitter API for logging in my users

In `active_admin.rb`, look for `config.current_user_method` and change the default value to `current_user` from `current_admin_user`

`config.current_user_method = :current_user`

Also change the `logout_link_path` to in your routes to include `as: :destroy_user_session`